# Show that $u_1(x)=x^a,u_2(x)=x^b$ are not solutions of the differential equation in any interval that contains the origin.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation :

> $y^{''} +py^{'}+qy=0$ where $p,q$ are continuous functions.

1.Show that $u_1(x)=x^a,u_2(x)=x^b$ are not solutions of the differential equation in any interval that contains the origin where $a,b>1$ are real.

2.Find $p,q$ such that $u_1,u_2$ are linearly independent solutions of the differential equation in some interval not containing the origin.

**My try**:

Since $u_1,u_2$ are solutions so they must satisfy the ODE:

$a(a-1)x^{a-2}+apx^{a-1}+qx^a=0$

$b(b-1)x^{b-2}+bpx^{b-1}+qx^b==0$

Multiplying the first equation by $x^b$ and second by $x^a$ we get the following:

$a(a-1)x^{a+b-2}+apx^{a+b-1}+qx^{a+b}=0$

$b(b-1)x^{a+b-2}+bpx^{a+b-1}+qx^{b+a}==0$

and solving we get:

$\dfrac{x^{a+b-2}}{ap-bq}=\dfrac{x^{a+b-1}}{b(b-1)q-qa(a-1)}=\dfrac{x^{a+b}}{a(a-1)bp-b(b-1)ap}$

But doing this also I cant prove that $u_1,u_2$ cant be solutions.

What should I do?

How should I find $p,q$?

Comment: $p(x) = q(x) = 0$ and $a = 0,b=1$ is a counterexample to statement 1.

Comment: @eyeballfrog;sorry i forgot to add the restrictions